# Sequelize many to many order association table by custom column

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

i am building a desktop app with electron and MySQL

1- how to order association table results by custom column in many to many association

```
 //Company model
    const Company = sequelize.define("Company", {
       name: {
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
      },    
    });
    
    //Branch Model
    const Branch = sequelize.define("Branch", {
        name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        },
        description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
       },
    });

    //Associations
    //join table
    const CompanyBranch = sequelize.define("CompanyBranch",
    {
    order: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    });

    Branch.belongsToMany(Company, {
    through: CompanyBranch,
    as: "Branches",
    });

    Company.belongsToMany(Branch, {
    through: CompanyBranch,
    });
```

2- how to map results to the correct shape instead of having nested object.

NB: in JavaScript `Branch.order //=> undefined`

My query

```
 //query
  const companies = await Company.findAll({include: [Branch]})
  //result
  {
   //company attrs
   Branches: [
   {id: 1, name: "branch 1", description: null, 
   CompanyBranch: { CompanyId: 1, ActivityId: 1,  BranchId: 1, order: 1}]
   }
```

The result i want to have

```
 {
   //company attrs
   Branches: [
   {id: 1, name: "branch 1", description: null,  order: 1}]
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use Sequelize literal to order by custom join table column

```
const companies = await Company.findAll({
include: [Branch],
order: [[Sequelize.literal("`Branches->CompanyBranch`.`order`"), "ASC"]]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `attributes` option to include the `CompanyBranch.order` field as the `order` field of Branch:

```
const companies = await Company.findAll({
  include: [
  {
     model: Branch,
     attributes: ['id', 'name', 'description', [Sequelize.col('CompanyBranch.order'), 'order']]
  }
]})
```

**Upd.**
If you wish to order by `CompanyBranch.order` then it's better to add associations from `Company` to `CompanyBranch` and from `CompanyBranch` to `Branch` (`hasMany` and `belongsTo` respectively) and use them like this:

```js
Company.hasMany(CompanyBranch);
CompanyBranch.belongsTo(Branch);
...
const companies = await Company.findAll({
  include: [
  {
     model: CompanyBranch,
     attributes: ['order'],
     include: [{
       model: Branch,
       attributes: ['id', 'name', 'description'] 
     },
  }],
  order: [['CompanyBranch', 'order', 'ASC']]
})
```

That way you can also indicate what fields you wish to get from `CompanyBranch` and from `Branch` even on the `CompanyBranch` level using notation like `['AssociationName.field', 'alias']`

Comment: not working i got this error: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Branches.CompanyBranch.order' in 'field list'

Comment: any idea how to order "Branches" by "order" column ?

Comment: If you wish to order by that column, maybe it would be a better idea first to include `CompanyBranch` and then include `Branch`.

Comment: i got this : Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

Comment: Check if `CompanyBranch` and `Branch` is actually Sequelize models